# Will iMessage receiver on iPad see my iPhone number?

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages, apple-id

I have had an older iPad with no cellular but recently I got an iPhone as well.  I would prefer people not seeing my phone number.

If I message them from my iPad will they now be able to see my iPhone number since both use the same Apple ID account?

Answer (score 1):

From [this Apple Support article:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201349#iOS)

> 1. For Messages, go to Settings > Messages and make sure that iMessage is on. If asked, sign in with the Apple ID you're using with Messages
>      and FaceTime on your iPhone. Then tap Send & Receive.
> 2. For FaceTime, go to Settings > FaceTime. If asked, sign in with the Apple ID that you're using with Messages and FaceTime on your iPhone.
> 3. Turn your phone number on or off:
>
>    - To turn on your phone number, select it and your Apple ID in the “You can be reached” section. If you don't see your phone number, get
>        help with your settings or contact Apple Support. If you see a number
>        that isn't yours, change your Apple ID password.
>    - To turn off your phone number, uncheck it.

Once you turn off your phone number at the "You can be reached" section people will see your email.